# Problem creating an XElement object with GML namespace

Tags: .net, namespaces, linq-to-xml, gml

I am trying to build a *XML* document using the *GML* namespace and **XML to LINQ**.

My goal is an `XElement` with contents like this:

```
<gml:name>...</gml:name>
```

But I get the following:

```
<name xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" />
```

The problem is that the `gml:` is missing from the element. Why is that?

---

My code is as follows:

```
XNamespace nsGML = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";
XElement item = new XElement(nsGML + "name");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all this XML

```
<name xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" />
```

is equivalent to this XML

```
<gml:name xmlns:gml="http://opengis.net/gml" />
```

And all XML consumers should treat it as same. That said you can achieve the second output like this:

```
XNamespace nsGML = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";
XElement item = new XElement(nsGML + "name",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "gml", nsGML.NamespaceName));
```

If you don't specify the namespace declaration attribute LINQ to XML will pick a prefix automatically for you (in this case it uses the empty one). If you want to force usage of a specific prefix you need to provide the namespace declaration attribute.

Comment: **Vitek**: Thanks for your quick reply. The equivalency I concluded, but I do want the visual appearance too - and your suggestion works like a charm :)